# Implicit declaration of function 'ccDrawSolidPoly' is invalid in C99

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Attempting to simply add in a joystick to control a sprite side to side, and up and down. The only non-outdated tutorial I can find for this, which is still a year old, simply get's me as far as 'Implicit declaration of function 'ccDrawSolidPoly' is invalid in C99'

[image]

.m
Code:

```
- (id)init
{
    // Apple recommend assigning self with supers return value
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return(nil);

    // Enable touch handling on scene node
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    [self initJoyStick];

    // done
    return self;
}
-(void)initJoyStick
{
    SneakyJoystickSkinnedBase *leftJoy = [[SneakyJoystickSkinnedBase alloc] init];
    [leftJoy setPosition:CGPointMake(64, 32)];
    leftJoy.backgroundSprite = [ColoredCircleSprite circleWithColor:[CCColor colorWithRed:255.0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:120.0] radius:32];
    leftJoy.thumbSprite = [ColoredCircleSprite circleWithColor:[CCColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:255.0 alpha:200.0] radius:16];
    leftJoy.joystick = [[SneakyJoystick alloc] initWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 128, 128)];
    joystick = leftJoy.joystick;
    [self addChild:joystick];

}
```

.h Code:

```
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "cocos2d-ui.h"
#import "SneakyJoystick.h"
#import "SneakyButton.h"
#import "SneakyButtonSkinnedBase.h"
#import "SneakyJoystickSkinnedBase.h"
#import "ColoredCircleSprite.h"
#import "ColoredSquareSprite.h"

@interface HelloWorldScene : CCScene
{
    SneakyJoystick *joystick;

}

+ (HelloWorldScene *)scene;
- (id)init;

@end
```

Any ideas or other ways of accomplishing this? I would highly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I had a fun time with this also.

The 2 header files `ColoredCircleSprite.h` and `ColoredSquareSprite.h` imported `cocos2d.h`. They also need to import `CCDrawingPrimitives.h`

This is the only way I could get it to work. Hope this helps.